# crash when using NSNumberFormatter to convert NSString to NSNumber

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I have a simple value in an NSSTRING that I want to convert to an NSNumber.  I do this all the time in my code and for some reason, this time it is not working.  Do you see anything wrong with this?

```
NSNumberFormatter * num_formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[num_formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *score;
NSString *mystr = [[player ScoresArray] objectAtIndex:currentKeeper - 1];


NSLog(@"here is my string: -%@-", mystr);
score = [num_formatter numberFromString:mystr];   // crash occurs on this line.  see error below...
NSLog(@"now it is: %d", [score intValue]);        // it never gets to this line...
```

Here is the output from the above code:

> here is my string: -3-

Here is the error I get:

```
2013-02-26 17:21:48.912 Golf Whiz[50407:c07] -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb5fa90
2013-02-26 17:21:48.912 Golf Whiz[50407:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb5fa90'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: `mystr` is an `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. Show how you define and assign a value to `mystr`.

Comment: Also... use %i instead of %d on the line it never got to when you do get it working... %d is for doubles... you took the "intValue" (INTEGER) so you want %i for integers.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw No, `%i` and `%d` are the same thing - used for `int`. `%f` is for `double`.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  Here is the definition of 'mystr'.          NSString *mystr = [[player ScoresArray] objectAtIndex:currentKeeper - 1];

Comment: @rmaddy My whole life of programming just flashed before my eyes! Hahaha, that explains a lot! So what is the difference between %i and %d then?

Comment: @phil Your `player` array must have `NSNumber` objects in it. At least at the index `currentKeeper - 1`. Add a log where you log `mystr`. `NSLog(@"mystr class = %@", [mystr class]);`.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw One starts with an `i` and the other starts with a `d`. That's the only difference.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw NaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaNNaN Batmaaaan! `%d` and `%i` are the same, d stands for decimal. `%lf` is for `double`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Crackin' me up haha! Okay, so decimal... like decimal points? Wouldn't it not be an integer at that point... or is it like, %d is only integers that have DECIMAL values... so something in base-16 (like hex (well.. deca-hex I should say)) could be assigned to %i but not to %d?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw It's not that. There are no "hexadecimal" or "decimal" integers. There are integes, and you can print them as decimal (using `%d` and `%i`) and hexadecimal (using `%x` and `%X`).

Comment: @H2CO3 So there is NO difference between %d and %i? What's the origin of 2 different things both doing the same thing then? Did classical coding languages use %d while others used %i and in modern times both were adapted because one might use one based of their programming history and background?

Comment: @H2CO3 According to the IEEE printf spec, the `l` modifier has no affect on `%f`. So you use `%f` for `double`, not `%lf`. Though using `%lf` isn't wrong.

Comment: Thanks, all, as suspected, it turns out that I did have nsnumber objects in the scoresArray afterall.  I have gone back and forth from string to num in this code so much that my head is about to explode.  sorry for the lame question - I would down-vote my own question now if I could...  lol.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the objects you're adding to ScoresArray are in fact strings, not NSNumbers.

Comment: Thanks for your support :) This belongs in the comment section for future reference, but keep up the good work of helping out others!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, all, as suspected, it turns out that I did have nsnumber objects in the scoresArray afterall.